# Integral $\int(\frac{1}{n+\cos x})^{\frac{3}{2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Find an expression for this indefinite integral.
I tried using some online calculators, but it is not coming.

$$\int\left(\dfrac{1}{n+\cos x}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}dx$$

Comment: Integral with respect to what variable?

Comment: @Demosthene: My money's on $x$. What do you think?

Comment: pardon me, i haven't give the correct expression, i mean to prove it for `n > 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- For $n=\pm1$, use the fact that $~\dfrac{1+\cos2t}2=\cos^2t~$ and $~\dfrac{1-\cos2t}2=\sin^2t$.
- For $n\neq\pm1$, use [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral). You should ultimately arrive at the following expression:

$\qquad\qquad$ [image]